# Как проверить корректность SSL-сертификата в Java?

Tags: java, безопасность, ssl

Есть код на Java, в котором я обращаюсь к стороннему серверу, отправляю туда POST-запрос и получаю в ответ JSON. В общих чертах код выглядит так:

```
// operationName - REST-операция на сервере, к которой я обращаюсь
// requestParams - запрос с серверу в JSON-формате (здесь описание того, что именно нужно вернуть) 

final StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

final URL url = new URL(SERVICE_HOST + SERVICE_ENDPOINT + operationName + "/?lang=rus");
final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
connection.setReadTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

final DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
outputStream.writeBytes(requestParams);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();

try (
    final InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
) {
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        content.append(inputLine);
    }
} catch (final Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Код предельно простой и делает то, что нужно.

Теперь я хочу изменить работу с внешним источником на работу через защищённый сокет (secured  socket). В общих чертах логика работы понятна, не понятно, что должно быть в методе *checkServerTrusted()* TrustManager'а.

Есть цепочка сертификатов. **Какие проверки необходимы и достаточны, чтобы проверить, что сертификат корректен и относится к сайту, к которому я обращаюсь?**

Фрагмент кода из [документации по JSSE (рус.)](https://spec-zone.ru/RU/Java/Docs/7/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#TrustManager):

```
 * Delegate to the default trust manager.
 */
public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
            throws CertificateException {
    try {
        pkixTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
    } catch (CertificateException excep) {
        /*
         * Possibly pop up a dialog box asking whether to trust the
         * cert chain.
         */
    }
}
```

— здесь предполагается спрашивать юзера, доверять ли цепочке сертификатов. Интересно, как организовать проверку по-правильному, с рукопожатием и прочим.

Comment: 1. цепочка сертификатов ведет к доверенному 2. срок действия сертификата не истек 3. сертификат не отозван